# Displaying CLLocation in label Xcode 7 Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

hey all i am brand new into coding iOS apps, and find it rather enjoyable so far..

I am having an issue assigning lat and lng to a text field. I have been following along in a tutorial but it crapped out and most examples i have found are in objective C and not swift.. and the ones in swift aren't all the best..

my ViewController is below:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class LocationVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var latField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lngField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var locateBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveBtn: UIButton!

    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 500

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        map.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        locationAuthStatus()
    }

    func locationAuthStatus() {
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            map.showsUserLocation = true
        } else {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

    func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, regionRadius * 1, regionRadius * 1)
        map.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
        if let loc = userLocation.location {
            centerMapOnLocation(loc)
        }

        let latField = location.longitude
        let lngField = location.latitude
    }

}
```

So far the map is moving, works on my device but I have no idea how to get the coords to appear..

Please forgive me if this is a noob question, but I just cant get this damn thing to go..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your mapView(_ :,didUpdatedUserLocation:) with this...

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    if let loc = userLocation.location 
    {
        centerMapOnLocation(loc)

        self.latField.text = "\(loc.coordinate.latitude)"
        self.lngField.text = "\(loc.coordinate.longitude)"
    }
}
```

Note: If you only need show the lat/lng could be a better idea to use an UILabel instead of UITextFiel

Comment: so this is spitting an error of Value of type "CLLocation" has no member 'latitude" and same exact message on Longitude. I Will convert the text fields to a UILabel now.

Comment: Hi @ShawnWilson, Fixed. :-)

Comment: that did it! Thanks!